# High messages_ready in Rabbitmq when using CELERY Consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery COnsumers and Rabbitmq for Publishing.
I am using upto 20 Worker Threads but as the time goes by, the messages_ready Count is very Huge.

Would this be a problem.
There would be hardly, few messages in the UNACKED count.

Have set message-ttl expires for Queue messages which doesnt work because i believe this doesnt work on messages in ready count.

How do i make sure, there are less messages in the "Ready" Count ?

Having high READY Count messages mean, that the Consumers are slow.
I also see the problem where consumers are not consuming after a point and the Ready Count doesnt go down at all.

Any Help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Add more workers so your Celery cluster consumes more messages.

Comment: Adding more consumers would not be a long term solution. Reason being, the messages are basically long processing processes which consumes memory. More the consumers, more processes consuming memory which might run out at some point.

Comment: Sure, I should have been more precise... I did not say "worker-processes", I said workers - in Celery parlance worker is the "arbiter" process that takes care of everything, including the management of worker-processes. Perhaps I should have called them nodes instead. I never have more than one worker on server running Celery, but I do have many worker-processes, depending on the machine specs... We also have long-running tasks (some up to 30 hours).

Comment: Yeah, I can try adding more nodes. Could you give me an example of how you would have configured your worker nodes and with what concurrency.